# Efficient Approach: Retrieve CLOB object from oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, java-8, oracle10g

Please suggest which is efficient way to retrieve CLOB data from Oracle 10g database where the data is XML and will both provide same complete content in case the data is in GB's,

```
        Clob myclob = null;
        myClob= resultSet.getClob("XML_DATA");
        InputStream inputstream = myClob.getAsciiStream();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(inputstream, writer);
        myXmlData = writer.toString().trim();
```

(or)

```
        String myXml= resultSet.getString("XML_DATA");
```

Comment: why do you think either are ineffecient?

Comment: In longer run where first will have lot of conversion and second is directly doing the conversion. So when we need to use the first and when to use second.

Comment: *premature optimization is the root of all evil*

Comment: First figure out **if** you have a problem

Comment: `ResultSet.getString` does no magic. It will have to go through the same operations you performed manually in the first step. But still, if it does exactly the same as the six statements of the first variant, why bother writing that verbose code instead of the one-liner? The main problem is not the way you retrieve the string, the main problem is *that* you retrieve that humongous string. The `Clob` API allows you to process the data on-the-fly without holding everything in RAM at once; if you only use it for reading the entire data into RAM to construct a `String` object, you gained nothing.